AWS Cognito master user with sub users (clients)
I looking to use AWS Cognito user pool in which there is a relationship between a "master" user and sub-users (clients).  The master user will initially create a cognito user account and then have the ability to create new Cognito users that are in essence clients of the "master" user.  This would be done using an AWS Amplify project with Flutter.  Does anyone know if this is possible using Cognito?

Seems like you're trying to build a multi-tenant solution. Cognito doesn't have a hierarchy of users, maybe you can build something custom with groups.
